# Capture First Character of Last Group of 1s in a Binary Series Part II: Multiple IDs

Tags: t-sql

I have data something like this:

```
ID      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Month   J F M A M J J A S O N D
Status  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1

ID      2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Month   J F M A M J J A S O N D
Status  1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1

ID      3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
Month   J F M A M J J A S O N D
Status  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Using t-SQL, I am trying to capture the month corresponding to the first `STATUS = 1` in the last group of 1s for each ID, i.e., September, November and December in this example.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp1

;WITH PARTITIONED1 AS

(SELECT   t0.ID
        , t0.Year_Month
        , LAST_VALUE(t0.Year_Month) OVER (PARTITION BY t0.Account_Number ORDER BY t0.Year_Month) AS STATUS
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t0.Account_Number ORDER BY t0.Year_Month) AS rn1

FROM #Temp0 t0
)

SELECT *
INTO #Temp1
FROM PARTITIONED1 p1
ORDER BY      t0.ID
            , t0.Year_Month


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM #Temp1 t1
WHERE t1.rn1 = (SELECT MAX(b.rn1) + 1 FROM #Temp1 b WHERE b.STATUS = 0)    
GROUP BY      t1.ID
        , t1.Year_Month
        , t1.rn1
```

However, this just returns the last instance where `STATUS = 1` is achieved overall as the first 1 of the last group of 1s, in this case January.

I've tried using CASE statements and grouping in various combinations (hence the intermediate step reading the data into #Temp1), but have not been able to get results for all three IDs; is anyone able to assist?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Ju for June and Jl for July:

```
--Sample Data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp0') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp0
CREATE TABLE #Temp0 (ID INT,    Year_Month VARCHAR(1),  Status INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp0
VALUES(1,'J',1),(1,'F',0),(1,'M',0),(1,'A',1),(1,'M',0),(1,'J',1),(1,'J',0),(1,'A',0),(1,'S',1),(1,'O',1),(1,'N',1),(1,'D',1),(2,'J',1),(2,'F',0),(2,'M',1),(2,'A',0),(2,'M',1),(2,'J',0),(2,'J',1),(2,'A',0),(2,'S',1),(2,'O',0),(2,'N',1),(2,'D',1),(3,'J',0),(3,'F',0),(3,'M',0),(3,'A',0),(3,'M',0),(3,'J',0),(3,'J',0),(3,'A',0),(3,'S',0),(3,'O',0),(3,'N',0),(3,'D',1);


--Query
WITH A
 AS ( SELECT *,
             CASE Year_Month
               WHEN 'J' THEN 1
               WHEN 'F' THEN 2
               WHEN 'M' THEN 3
               WHEN 'A' THEN 4
               WHEN 'M' THEN 5
               WHEN 'Ju' THEN 6
               WHEN 'Jl' THEN 7
               WHEN 'A' THEN 8
               WHEN 'S' THEN 9
               WHEN 'O' THEN 10
               WHEN 'N' THEN 11
               WHEN 'D' THEN 12
             END
      AS MonthNumber
      FROM #Temp0 ),
 StartingPoints
 AS ( SELECT ID,
             Year_Month,
             MonthNumber,
             Status
      FROM A
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT 1
        FROM A
        AS B
        WHERE B.ID=A.ID
              AND B.Status=A.Status-1
      ) ), 
 MonthRanking
 AS ( SELECT A.*,
             ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER( PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.MonthNumber )
      AS rownum
      FROM A
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT ID,
               MAX( MonthNumber )+1
        AS StartOfLastGroup
        FROM StartingPoints
        GROUP BY ID
      )
      AS B
      ON A.ID=B.ID
         AND A.MonthNumber>=B.StartOfLastGroup )
 SELECT *
 FROM MonthRanking
 WHERE rownum=1;
```

Results:

[image]

If Month Names are recorded in Full as in July, June then this would work as well:

```
WITH StartingPoints
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Year_Month,
                MonthNUmber = MONTH('01-'+Year_Month+'-2010'),
                Status
         FROM #Temp0
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (
             SELECT 1
             FROM #Temp0 AS B
             WHERE B.ID = #Temp0.ID
                   AND B.Status = #Temp0.Status - 1
         )),
     MonthRanking
     AS (SELECT A.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY MONTH('01-'+A.Year_Month+'-2010')) AS rownum
         FROM #Temp0 AS A
              INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT ID,
                    MAX(MonthNumber) + 1 AS StartOfLastGroup
             FROM StartingPoints
             GROUP BY ID
         ) AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
                   AND MONTH('01-'+A.Year_Month+'-2010') >= B.StartOfLastGroup)
     SELECT *
     FROM MonthRanking
     WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Results:

[image]

And if we assume that the data is as Iamdave assumes then it simply like so:

```
WITH StartingPoints
     AS (SELECT ID,
                Year_Month,
                Status
         FROM #Temp0
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (
             SELECT 1
             FROM #Temp0 AS B
             WHERE B.ID = #Temp0.ID
                   AND B.Status = #Temp0.Status - 1
         )),
     MonthRanking
     AS (SELECT A.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY Year_Month) AS rownum
         FROM #Temp0 AS A
              INNER JOIN
         (
             SELECT ID,
                    MAX(Year_Month) + 1 AS StartOfLastGroup
             FROM StartingPoints
             GROUP BY ID
         ) AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
                   AND A.Year_Month >= B.StartOfLastGroup)
     SELECT *
     FROM MonthRanking
     WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: ...this seems a little overly complex

Comment: @iamdave taking advantage of the lead function is good but what if they are using an earlier version of sql server? Lets say 2008

Comment: @iamdave Simplified as we do not need to identify Island and troughs

Comment: I think it safe to assume usage of software that is already 5 years old unless specified otherwise.  I think we should always offer newer solutions that take advantage of improvements unless we know they are not available as otherwise those seeking answers may well get one that is no longer the best course of action.

Comment: @iamdave please see my latest modification to the answer

Comment: HI Kamran,

Your code runs just fine for me in a couple of seconds, but when I add in the other required variables for t0 and run the code over 5yrs on one test ID, it's taking forever - 10mins and counting.  Is the CTE approach less suitable for a larger dataset over several years?  I have used then in the past, but would hardly describe myself as an expert...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: CTE is in memory where as using temp tables uses tempdb and number of reads from disk increases. Using Case statements slow things down so if you can somehow eliminate the use of the case statement then the query will run faster. How many rows of data are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Kamran - ultimately several thousand IDs over maybe ten years!  I'd kinda figured that the case statement wasn't pulling its weight; I will try to find an alternative.  Thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a couple derived tables that stack two window functions on top of one another (which can't be done in the same `select`).  I have assumed that your data is slightly different to the table you have provided, based on the column names in your query.  If they are not as I have them below, I strongly recommend having a look at how you store your data:

```
declare @t table(ID int, YearMonth int,StatusValue bit);
insert into @t values (1,201501,1),(1,201502,0),(1,201503,0),(1,201504,1),(1,201505,0),(1,201506,1),(1,201507,0),(1,201508,0),(1,201509,1),(1,201510,1),(1,201511,1),(1,201512,1),(2,201601,1),(2,201602,0),(2,201603,1),(2,201604,0),(2,201605,1),(2,201606,0),(2,201607,1),(2,201608,0),(2,201609,1),(2,201610,0),(2,201611,1),(2,201612,1),(3,201701,0),(3,201702,0),(3,201703,0),(3,201704,0),(3,201705,0),(3,201706,0),(3,201707,0),(3,201708,0),(3,201709,0),(3,201710,0),(3,201711,0),(3,201712,1);

with c as
(
    select ID
            ,YearMonth
            ,StatusValue
            ,case when StatusValue = 1
                     and lead(StatusValue,1,1) over (partition by ID
                                                     order by YearMonth desc) = 0
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end as c
    from @t
), sc as
(
    select ID
            ,YearMonth
            ,StatusValue
            ,sum(c) over (partition by ID order by YearMonth desc) as sc
    from c
    where c = 1
)
select ID
        ,YearMonth
        ,StatusValue
from sc
where sc = 1
order by ID;
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| ID | YearMonth | StatusValue |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |    201509 |           1 |
|  2 |    201611 |           1 |
|  3 |    201712 |           1 |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```